# How to manually open twitter's "more tweets" page?

Tags: twitter

Once or twice a day, the Twitter app on my phone shows a notification that shows me one highlighted tweet followed by "More Tweets".

How can I get to this list of tweets manually? If I dismiss the notification, I can't get to this page.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about the trend suggestions, which include a "More Tweets" button to load more such suggestions.

On the Desktop Twitter Website this button can be found in the top right: [image: On the Desktop Twitter Website this button can be found in the top right]

If that's what you mean, then you can find all trends by visiting this link: https://twitter.com/i/trends

Mobile equivalent: https://mobile.twitter.com/i/trends

It will show trending worldwide, unless you have your twitter settings changed to only show certain countries.

Comment: No, not this one. Exactly the one I describe. I don't even know how it's called.

Comment: Could you then please add a picture of which button is meant, since it's not clear from your Question description.